# Rails: make scope data persist from index to show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a job index page with a list of jobs.  There are "filters" that a user can apply where i use scopes to limit the results based on some type of criteria such as "experience"

when a user clicks on a job in the index page they get to the jobs show page where i have a breadcrumb.  if they click on that bread crumb to go back to the jobs index page all of the filters set through the scopes have been wiped out.

a user should be able to 1) set a search filter on the index 2) have the search results trimmed 3) click on a link to the jobs show page 4) be able to click on the breadcrumb navigation back to the jobs index page and have all the scopes still be applied.  I have 1-3 working, just can't figure out #4 right now.

I'm not sure how to persist that scope data from the index page once i click through to the jobs show page.  I'm guessing if i can store it then i can pass it as a parameter when i'm going back to the index page?

my navigation breadcrumb in the jobs show page

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><%= link_to "Search Results", filtered_jobs_path(experience: params[:experience]) %></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Job Details</li>
  </ol>
</nav>

      <% if params[:experience].present? %>
        <%= 'test' %>
      <% end %>
```

my scope in the model

```
 scope :by_experience, -> (ex) { where(experience: ex) if ex.present? }
```

calling scope in the controller which is part of the index action

```
    # scopes
  if params[:experience].present? 
    @jobs = @jobs.by_experience(params[:experience])
  end
```

The jobs index partial that lists the job names

```
<div class="jobs_index_middle_panels col-md-6">

<!-- displays error message if search term can't be found, ignores nil values -->  
<% filter_array = [ params[:experience], 
params[:num_days_past], params[:company], params[:search], params[:l] ].compact %>

<% if @jobs.present? %>
  <!--kaminari gem helper method-->
  <h5 class="text1"><%= page_entries_info @jobs, entry_name: 'job' %></h5>
<% else %>
  <h5 class="text1">No jobs found. Try removing the following filters:  
  <span class="text-danger"><%= filter_array.join(", ") %></span></h5>
<% end %>


    <% @jobs.each do |job| %>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="vert-spacing2"><%= link_to job.title, job_url(job.id), class: "text-danger" %></h4>
          <div class="vert-spacing1"><%= job.company %></div>
          <div class="vert-spacing1"><%= truncate(job.description, length: 200, separator: ' ') %></div>
          <b><%= job.city.capitalize %>, <%= job.state %></b>
          <span class="pull-right"><%= time_ago_in_words(job.created_at) + " ago" %></span>
          <%= number_to_currency(job.salary) %>
        </div>
      </div><br>

   <% end %><!--./jobs-->

  <!--pagination: uses kaminari gem -->
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
      <%= paginate @jobs %>
    </ul>
  </nav>     



</div><!--./jobs_index_middle_panels-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit your filters to the session.

```
if params[:experience].present?
  session[:filter_on_experience] = params[:experience]
end
if session[:filter_on_experience].present?
  @jobs = @jobs.by_experience(params[:experience])
end
```

What you are doing here is changing your scope to filter on the session data instead of the params. If there are params, it will reset your session data for the paramater (name your session[:foo] accordingly). If there is session data it will do the scope. No session data, no scope.

It is worth while to add a clear session data method if the page is refreshed. Otherwise your records will be scoped until the user clears cookies!

Comment: interesting.  I would need to make it work for users both with and without signing in though.  so don't think i could use your suggestion.

Comment: In that case make the Params uniquely named and pass them back and forth in your link_to’s. foo_bar_path(my_param1: param1,  my_param2: param2...) it’s lots of hard coding but it would work.

Comment: Better yet, make your show content render in a modal so your user never actually leaves the index page.

Comment: I ended up passing the parameters back and forth using link_to in my index and show templates like you suggested.  worked out good.  thanks!